# Why is Windows 10 IoT Dashboard unable to find my Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: windows-iot

I've found that discovering my device using the Windows 10 IoT tools has been extremely difficult and unreliable. I've been pretty excited about Windows 10 on IoT devices but the ease of using them and writing meaningful software and learn from it has been pathetic. Forums suggest that I need to connect via Ethernet, but the device Surface Pro 4 I use is connected via Wifi and I can't of on the same IP address if I RPi wired and go wireless for my Surface which I use for development work. Can anybody suggest some ways to make life easier to use the setup? Am I the only one going through this? If I am, I'd be oddly surprised. Any tips/help is much appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you are the only one going through this. Log into tour router and check the DHCP table... find your Pi''s IP. Ping it from your device. If you cant ping it from your DEV device... there is no chance the discovery device will find it. I don't get the difference between LAN and WiFi. They should be the same network, if they not.. then that's your problem?  PS Is the tool unreliable (as in only works sometimes or you just having a general rant?)

Comment: And you do realise its Windows IoT on the Pi.... and NOT Windows 10

Comment: I am able to ping RPi, Its just that the Dashboard doesn't find it. Also, When I said wired connection for the RPi, My ISP had configured 4 connections that I could access over WiFi. I also have data cable running through the house and has 4 access points. My Windows IoT Dashboard definitely doesn't see when connecting the RPi over cable, Over Wifi connecting to the same Wifi access point, I see it sometime but don't, most of the times, which is very frustrating.

Comment: Sounds like a misconfigured network. Probably the dashboard tries dns lookups and it fails due to flakiness in the network. Dns resolves on the DHCP router so even if you use the same AP it may have troubles resolving local DNS. Cause ipscan would work fine. It's frustrating because some routers suck and cause these problems :(

Comment: I figured out the cause of the problem with a bit of poking around. Apparently there is a process called ebootpinger.exe that needs to be running on the RPi for it to be discoverable by the IOT Dashboard. I started a remote Powershell session and started it and boom, there it goes, It started to appear on my dashboard. Thanks for looking and posting responses to my questions!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can log into your router and look under device list.

Im using filezilla to connect to mine. Ive made a wildlife camera for our garden. Rather than keep taking sd card out to view my videos i just connect remotely and drag files accross to my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

ebootpinger.exe will do the trick.
I opened powershell remote for my rasp, executed this command.
IOT Dashboard then listed my rasp under 'My Devices'